# CiviCRM for political campaign

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicampaign

We have a custom application which has been used in to election cycles.  We are thinking of converting to the CiviCRM platform.  Can CiviCRM be configured to run a political campaign?

Comment: Hi Christopher. There are many political organisations using CiviCRM. We have worked with a bunch and can elucidate about those if that helps and you want to get in touch. But given that 'political campaigns' can take many forms in the many jurisdictions around the world, i think you will get more useful answers if you explain more about the features that would be the deal maker/killer in regard to a CRM.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. CiviCRM can manage

- fundraising
- volunteer management
- phone banking
- door knocking
- Get Out The Vote
- event management (think fundraising events, or getting folk for a door-knocking bash).

As per my comment above though, what really matters is what you need to achieve your political goals.